# Using Zxing QrCodeWriter.encode with .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, bitmap, windows-phone-8.1, zxing

I am trying to Generate a QR code using the Zxing Library for Windows Phone. This is the code which I am trying to reuse:

```
Bitmap img = new Bitmap(size, size);
Color Color = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);

for (int y = 0; y < matrix.Height; ++y)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < matrix.Width; ++x)
    {
        Color pixelColor = img.GetPixel(x, y);
        if (matrix.get_Renamed(x, y) == -1)
        {
            img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White );
        }
        else
        {
            img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black);
        }
    }
}
img.Save(@"c:test.bmp",ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

But in .NET 4.5 `System.Drawing` is not available so the references to `Bitmap`, `Color`, and `ImageFormat` are not resolved.

What are the equivalent objects for the above-mentioned objects?

Answer (score 0):

Use `WriteableBitmap`. It might be a bit more difficult to use than `Bitmap`, but there's quite a little information on the internet about it.

Comment: @kennyzx Yep. Googling it in Russia gives me a lot of articles related to it. I'm pretty sure Google UK or USA would give even more information.

Comment: I mean you have a typo in your answer. OR is it correct English usage I don't know?

Comment: @kennyzx You mean not `quite a little` but `quite a lot of`? I'm not a native English speaker, but these are equivalent, aren't they?